# JPA OnetoOne mapping returns null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following table in the DB:

```
material (id_mat, name, initial_weight, cargo_number, exp_date, left_amount)
```

I had to add an additional table, which shows constructions that were built using the materials from `material` table. Here how it looks:

```
material_construction (mat_id, construction_number)
```

I then created an entity class called `MatConstructionMapping` for the table `material_construction`:

```
@Entity(name = "material_construction")
public class MatConstructionMapping implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1739614249257235075L;

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "mat_id", referencedColumnName = "id_mat", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Material mat;

    @Column(name="construction_number")
    private Integer number;

    public Integer getConNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

And, added following getter in the `Material`entity:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "mat_id")
public MatConstructionMapping getMaterialConstructionNumber() {
    return conNumber;
}
```

The issue is that, when I am retrieving the `conNumber` for any materials, its always `null`, however there are the values in the DB. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot have JoinColumn at both sides, @JoinColumn should be at the owning entity which you can define in any side in one to one relation, the other side should have mappedBy attribute to indicate the reverse relation, say for example MatConstructionMapping is the owning entity, then you should edit your Material

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="mat")
public MatConstructionMapping getMaterialConstructionNumber() {
  return conNumber;
}
```